# Charms bar using Metro UI CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, microsoft-metro

I am new to web development.........

I have used [Metro UI CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/) to create [this](http://apps.engineerinme.com/dufferzafar/metroMe/)

I am now trying to emulate a Charms Bar.

I want that when the user clicks on theme button a bar should be displayed on the right containing some controls etc. The bar should hide when it loses focus (user clicks outside the bar).

The Charms bar is added using `<div class="charms">` I have also added `style="display:none;"` so that the bar is not visible on start.

Then I used the following code to show it when the user selects the theme button or text

```
$(document).click(function(event) 
{
var $target = $(event.target);
var target = event.target;

if (!target.id.indexOf("theme")) //if the target id contains "theme" then show charms bar
{
    $("div .charms").fadeIn(600)
}

else
{
    if (target.id != "charms")  //if the charms bar itseff is NOT clicked
        $("div .charms").fadeOut(600)
}   
});
```

I don't like this code because when i click a control in the charms bar, it hides the bar itself.

All i need to do is to create a floating bar, that is visible when the user clicks a button, and hides when the user clicks something else.......

Answer (score 2):

Are you taking about, Something like this :

```
Use Event Like mousemove : to populate Charms bar see below :
```

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/4pCsS/2/)

Move your mouse to window right.